# HTML5 draggable on CKEditor with Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

In application I have to automate there's a custom CKEditor plugin that allows to drop element on CKEditor contents (there's an 'drop' event handled on the CKEditor end).

Everything works fine while playing with it manually, but unfortunately, running both action-chain approach and js-based workaround doesn't work with Selenium. The element gets clicked (the outline appears), but it doesn't get moved and there's no drop at all.

I think that there should be a way to fire an event to the CKEditor, but the target element might be wrong (I tried the iframe, the body, the editor element) and the solution to that problem would be to find appropiate element.

Tested on all currently used browsers (Chrome 69, Firefox 62) with newest drivers available.

Comment: Code trials please